# when I will use the newest docker.io version through the ubuntu archive

Tags: docker

i'm writting to inquire about docker.io package pathch.
i noticed that docker.io package in my ubuntu bionic server is not the lastest version. So, I need to patch docker.io. But I couldn't upgrade to latest docker.io(18.09.2) through the 'apt-get upgrade docker.io' command.
But I just could use only 18.06.1 version.  And I noticed that docker.io latest version(18.09.2) is in launchpad site.

So I wondering when the updated version will be applied to the ubuntu pacakage or archive. When I will know the schedule or plan.... of course,
I know the method that changing repository sources or source-list. But I can't use this method due to something sucurity issues.

Any answer and reply comments will be welcomed and appreciated.

Thanks,,

Comment: As of today, it's in the -proposed pocket of 16.04 and 18.04 for testing. See for yourself using the command `apt-cache madison docker.io`. It will be released into -universe and become available for upgrading when testing is complete. Testing is complete when it is complete - no schedule. More volunteer testers means faster release. It's already released for 18.10.

Comment: Thanks, I confirmed that latest version(18.09.2) is released for Cosmic Cuttlefish.  And I'd like to just know the date(change the pocket from "proposed" to updates,security,release) for bionic Beaver approximately...

Comment: Testing is complete when it is complete - no schedule

Comment: using the command apt-cache madison docker.io in bionic, i can see below...

docker.io|18.06.1-0ubuntu1.2~18.04.1|http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu~~
docker.io|18.06.1-0ubuntu1.2~18.04.1|http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu ~~
something is wrong???  Please check the status...

Comment: What makes you believe something is wrong?